# Matplotlib: Customizing Qt4Agg Backend

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to customize the Qt4Agg backend.  To ensure that I didn't insert any bugs, as a starting point, I copied matplotlib/backends/backend_qt4agg.py to a new location on my PYTHONPATH, renamed it "my_backend.py", and corrected two import statements as follows:

```
from backend_agg import ...
from backend_qt4 import ...
```

becomes

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import ...
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4 import ...
```

In my matplotlib RC file I changed the backend to module://my_backend.py.

When plotting from a script using "show()", everything works as normal.  But when trying to execute within an ipython session started with "ipython --pylab", the figure shows up, but nothing ever plots and I get a spinning wheel.  How can I fix this?

I am using OSX Mavericks, Python 2.7.3, IPython 1.1.0, and Matplotlib 1.3.1.

Thanks

Comment: because some of the magic hooks that need to be set up in pyplot are not correct.  What exactly are you trying to do? There is probably an easier way than duplicating the entire backend.

Comment: I added hardcopy printing and an icon to the toolbar.  I also need to override the mouse_move of the toolbar.

Comment: Then just override the toolbar used, that definitely does not require a whole new backend.  Also see https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/wiki/Mep22

Comment: I use the pyplot interface almost exclusively, i.e. "figure(); plot(data); ...".  To keep this workflow, I did not see a way to override only the navigation toolbar.  If this is possible, please tell me how. Thanks.

Comment: This super hacky and touches the internals (so in might break with out warning) but just override `backend_qt4.FigureManagerQt4._get_toolbar` to return an instance of your toolbar class.

Comment: and monkey-patch it in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurs because the GUI main loop fails to start because IPython does not recognize the backend, and therefore, it doesn't know which GUI to use.  This can be remedied by manually starting the GUI main loop in an IPython startup file.  In ~/.ipython/profile_default/startup/my_backend_start_gui.py I placed the following code:

```
import matplotlib
if matplotlib.rcParams['backend'] == 'module://my_backend':
    from IPython.lib.inputhook import enable_gui
    enable_gui('qt4')
```

Now everything works fine.